# tr does not contain the children th jQuery

Tags: jquery, tr

I am having a table row in which `#context_menu` is a last item. as I want to check `tr` is not a header row. i.e. `tr` must not have a child `th`.

```
$("#context_menu li").click(function(){
        var tr1 = $(this).parents("tr");
            var parent_tr = tr1.prev();
            //Here the code goes to check  is not a header row.
            //Since I want something like this
             if($( parent_tr+":contains('th')" ).length == 0)
             {
               alert("found desired row")
             }   
    })
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `.find()` to see the occurence of element within selector.try this:

```
       $("#context_menu li").click(function(){
        var tr1 = $(this).closest("tr");
        var parent_tr = tr1.prev();
        if(!$( parent_tr ).find('th').length)//or $( parent_tr ).find('th').length == 0
        {
          alert("found desired row")
        }
       })};
```

Answer (score 1):

`parent_tr` is a jQuery object use `find()`:

```
var parent_tr = tr1.prev();
//Here the code goes to check  is not a header row.
//Since I want something like this
if (parent_tr.find("th").length == 0) {
    alert("found desired row")
}
```